# How to create text substitution in command line instead of System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

Tags: mac, terminal, macos-sierra

Is there any way to create text substitutions in the command line instead of `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Text`?

I see that when you export text substitutions, it creates an html file, so I'm not sure whether you need to create a similar html file to import them.

The reason for this is I have lots of shortcut keys that were created in Windows and would like to re-create them on a Mac. I would hate to have to create each of them in the GUI. I was wondering if there was a command line alternative as a Mac is a Unix flavored OS.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for generating the plist file to be imported would be a simple Python script. Python has built-in support for apple plist files.

Assuming a file (CSV) called "substitutions.csv" with the "shortcut" and "phrase" headers.

```
shortcut,phrase
mename,Frodo
```

And the Python script `generate_substitions.py` in the same folder as the `.csv` file above.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import plistlib

with open('./substitutions.plist', 'wb+') as _plist:
    with open('./substitutions.csv') as _f:
        csvfile = csv.DictReader(_f)
        plistlib.dump(list(csvfile), _plist)
```

Run this in in the terminal.

```
chmod +x generate_substitutions.py
./generate_substitutions.py
```

Then drag the generated `.plist` file into the System Preferences > Keyboard > "Text" text substitutions window. New substitions are added and existing ones (matching on the shortcut) are updated.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this drag-and-drop technique of plist files does not seem to work anymore on Ventura

Answer (score 0):

Although you wanted a command line solution to your problem, AppleScript is by far the better choice in this case, as generating new plist data is much simpler.

My script below will take the contents of a specified CSV text file that contains your old Windows text substitutions, and uses it to generate a `.plist` file that you can import directly into *System Preferences* via drag-n-drop.

To run the script, you'll need to open up *Script Editor* and set make the following minor adjustments to suit your specific options:

- Change the value of the property `csvf` (line 1) to the path where you CSV file can be located.  I had mine on the *Desktop*, and it was called `substitutions.txt`;
- If you really feel strongly about it, you can change the value of the property `plistf` (line 2) to a new path.  However, this file is temporary, and you'll be trashing it later when you're done;
- Lastly, change the property `text item delimiters` to the character that acts as a field separator for your CSV data.  I currently set it to `|`, and my sample CSV file looked like this:

  ```
  ABCDEFG|äbçdêfg
  1234567|0000000
  ```

  which corresponds to two text substitutions, the first of which maps `ABCDEFG` to international lowercase equivalents, and the second of which maps `1234567` to seven zeroes.

The script has plenty of comments in to describe what each part does.   But it's also very short and won't need too much attention paid to it.  After it has run, the file `substitutions.plist` should appear on your Desktop.  Open *System Preferences > Keyboard > Text* and drag the `.plist` file onto the big list box to import them straight away.

```
    property csvf : "~/Desktop/substitutions.txt" -- CSV file containing substitions to import
    property plistf : "~/Desktop/substitutions.plist" -- Plist file to which data is outputted 
    property text item delimiters : "|" -- The CSV field separator used in the csvf file
    property ReplacementItem : {phrase:missing value, shortcut:missing value}
    global ReplacementItems

    on run
        set ReplacementItems to {} -- a list to store text replacement record data

        -- Read CSV values from text file and use
        -- them to create new text replacement items
        readFromCSVFile at csvf

        -- Create plist file
        tell application "System Events" to set the value ¬
            of (make new property list file ¬
            with properties {name:plistf}) ¬
            to the ReplacementItems
    end run

    -- This handler receives arguments A and B, and creates
    -- a new text replacement record that will be used to
    -- map (substitute) text A to text B.
    on textReplacementToMap from A as text to B as text
        local A, B

        tell the ReplacementItem
            set its shortcut to A
            set its phrase to B
        end tell

        copy the ReplacementItem to the end of the ReplacementItems
    end textReplacementToMap

    -- This handler receives a file path to a CSV file
    -- that contains a CSV-formatted list of text
    -- substitutions that will be read and used to create
    -- the new text replacement mappings
    to readFromCSVFile at f as text
        local f

        tell application "System Events"
            if not (file f exists) then return
            set POSIXfile to the POSIX path of file f
        end tell

        read the POSIXfile as «class utf8»

        repeat with CSVitem in paragraphs of result
            try
                set [A, B] to CSVitem's text items
                textReplacementToMap from A to B
            end try
        end repeat
    end readFromCSVFile
```